# Java: List<E> know E.getClass()

Tags: java, collections, wildcard

As we all know the Generics about Java Collections that `E` or a wildcard `?` is required to instantiate the allowed contents / objects in a particular collection.

My question is there a way we could know the wildcard or object of a particular collection from the code below?

```
Object inbound = java.io.ObjectInputStream().readObject();
if(inbound instanceof List<?>) {
   // know `?.getClass()`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only find the type parameters if `inbound` is a class that defines its type parameters in a type declaration. For example, suppose you serialized an instance of `NodeList` that was declared like this:

```
final class NodeList extends ArrayList<Node> { }
```

Then when you deserialize it, you can do this:

```
Object inbound = ois.readObject();
if (inbound instanceof List<?>) {
  Type t = inbound.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
  if (t instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
    for (Type p : pt.getActualTypeArguments()) {
      if (p instanceof TypeVariable<?>)
        System.out.println("Unknown");
      else
        System.out.println(p); /* Prints "interface Node" */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No. Due to type erasure, during runtime there is no way to differentiate between `List`s.

Comment: Generics is all done at compile time. It is basically extra compiler checking and syntactic sugar. None of the generics type information is available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you would be certain that the list contains at least one element, in which case you could simply call `getClass` on that.

Otherwise this wouldn't really be possible, although you could serialize the correct Class object along with the List.

Comment: Is there a way to get `E` without getting into the elements of `List<?>`? As of now this is the nearest answer I would be accepting.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best solution if you need to do this is with Guice: http://blog.publicobject.com/2008/11/guice-punches-erasure-in-face.html.

As others have mentioned, type erasure is the source of the problems.  A good explanation is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html.

You can take a look at [the source for `ArrayList`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) and see an example of how this works.  The `ArrayList` is holding an `Object[]` (line 111).  It doesn't know the types of the objects.  You can see that the 'type safety' is actually just achieved via casts, e.g. line 371.

Comment: But this solution would invalid if the `List.size() == 0`.

Comment: I don't see why the `TypeLiteral` route wouldn't work even if the list size is 0.  The sample in the blog post to which I linked should work fine without any elements.  Your question says you want "`// know ?.getClass()`".  You could call `TypeLiteral.getRawType()` to get the `Class`.